# Is it possible to deploy Free Trial Container Service with DC/OS orchestrator using only 4 cores?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-container-service

Is it possible to deploy Free Trial Container Service with DC/OS orchestrator using only 4 cores? I am trying to deploy the Container Service with DC/OS but I always get deployment fail regardless the settings (at least 6 cores required).

Here are the photos of example configuration:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQgl4.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to deploy Free Trial Container Service with DC/OS
>   orchestrator using only 4 cores?

Unfortunately, for now it is **not** possible to create ACS DC/OS with 4 cores, because Azure Marketplace create ACS DC/OS with one master and two nodes, at least we need **six** cores.
One master and two nodes:

[image]

```
Master:             2 cores  
Private agent:      2 cores  
Public agent:       2 cores
```

As a workaround, we can create **two Azure VMs**, and deploy DC/OS on those VMs, here is the DC/OS system requirements:

[image]

More information about DC/OS system requirements, please refer to this [link](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/administration/installing/custom/system-requirements/).

For now, the free trial with a **limit of 4 cores**, here is the feedback about [it](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/16926685-up-the-core-limit-on-the-azure-free-trial-to-at-le), maybe we can upvote this feedback.